# Load content on mouseover

Tags: javascript, jquery, onmouseover

I want to load the content of a div on the mouseover of an icon within the div. Furthermore, the mouseover should only fire once and preferably the icon should disappear after loading the content.

The content that will be loaded in de div will be an external file with social media buttons. In case you are wondering; I don't want them to load with the rest of the page because they slow it down. Also, some visitors might not be comfortable with sites like FB and G+ tracking their internet movement.

So, I have gathered some code and copy pasted a bit and this is what I came up with:

```
<div id="social_media">

<img src="icon.png" onmouseover="javascript:$('#social_media').load('external_file.php'); this.onmouseover=null;" alt="Show Social Media Buttons!" />

</div>
```

The thing is, it works perfectly fine :) But since it is code that I got from 3 different sources and pasted together, my question is if it's any good? For example, I never tried to find a way to remove the icon on mouseover, it just did :)

I have almost no experience in coding Javscript/jQuery, so please let me know what you think about it so that I can learn from it!

Thanks and greetings from Amsterdam!

Comment: "But since it is code that I got from 3 different sources and pasted together, my question is if it's any good?" --- if it works - it is good. Stackoverflow is a community of developers (and for developers) not copy-pasters

Comment: @zerkms right but go easy on the OP he is just new here :)

Comment: @john: ok. He copied some answer somewhere, and now you're improving it. The sad thing is that SO becoming a place for doing work for free

Comment: @zerkms: I disagree. He tried something, and asks for opinions about this. IMO, this is perfectly acceptable, and I'm totally fine with that. If you don't wanna answer, just don't.

Comment: @zerkms i didn't disagree with you, one he is new second may be he is at the very start of his career and needs a little push lets not discourage him, maybe he learns very quickly and one day you never know become a valueable member of the community ...

Comment: @Pierre: "He tried something" --- what "something"? I see: a) the description of what should be done b) Frankenstein solution assembled from different sources c) explanation that OP doesn't have any experience. Where are the attempts of doing something you're talking about?

Comment: @zerkms: I see the descreption of what should be done, and a piece of code that **works** and serves its goal (however ugly). The question is obviously not perfect, but IMO, it is acceptable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

avoid the inline code  try

```
<div id="social_media">

<img src="icon.png"  alt="Show Social Media Buttons!" />

</div>
```

attach a `mouseenter` event handler to the `img`

```
$(function(){// short cut of $(document).ready(); read more on google
    $("#social_media>img").bind({
        mouseenter:function(e){
         $('#social_media').load('external_file.php');
        }
    });
});
```

P.S the selectors are not optimized nor the outcome of this code it was just to give you an idea

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/UMBPt/1/)

Comment: This doesn't make the callback be called only once... :/

Answer (score 1):

Several things to note:

- You really should avoid inline JavaScript code in HTML, that's not clean at all. Move it to an external JavaScript file of possible, or, at least, in a separate `<script>` tag. It will be ways easier to maintain.
- Using this method to fire the event only once seems odd. You should use the jQuery `one` method, which is made exactly for that.
- The icon just disappears because the `load` method replaces the content of the div in which the icon is.

For example, IMO, the code should be:

```
 $('#social_media').one('mouseover', function(){
   $(this).load('external_file.php');
 });
```

Answer (score 1):

The answer to your real question is "the code is kinda middling."  The reason the icon went away is because when you called `load` you replaced it.  Internally your document is a tree of piece of the document called the DOM, for "document object model" -- abusing terminology, since that tree is actually an expression of the model, not the model itself.

There's a node in that tree that is your `div`, and it contains a node with the icon `img`.  When you do the `load()`, that node is replaced with what you loaded.

As @john says, it's undesirable to put code like that inline, because when you want to figure out what it's doing later, it can be hard to find.