# How to load a WordPress loop on mouseover?

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, loops, mouseover

I'm building a WordPress theme with a dropdown navigation menu that loads five of the latest posts in each category. To do so, I've created separate template parts for each loop that appears once the user has hovered over its navigation menu item. It's supposed to work much like what they have over at http://www.theverge.com/

But loading everything at once would be a bit troublesome for the server under heavy traffic, wouldn't it? So I only want to load each template part on mouseover on its parent `li` item.

**Here's some of the code:**

```
<ul>
<!-- First item -->
<li><a href="#">News</a>
    <ul class="inner">
        <?php get_template_part( 'loadheadlines' ); ?>
    </ul>
</li>
<!-- Second item -->
<li><a href="#">Features</a>
    <ul class="inner">
        <?php get_template_part( 'loadnews' ); ?>
    </ul>
</li>
</ul>
```

How should I approach this? What kind of script should I use to only load `<?php get_template_part( 'loadheadlines' ); ?>` on mouseover? 
I saw [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10777103/load-content-on-mouseover), but I'm a bit confused on how I should make it work on WordPress. And, since I'm fairly novice, I had to ask the pros. I know it's supposed to be an easy one, but I'm kind of stuck here.

Thanks in advance for taking the time to answer, guys.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, to load content dynamically, you need to use AJAX.

Essentially, with ajax you execute javascript, which will in turn execute server side code (such as the wordpress loop which is in PHP) and you will get the result in the javascript asynchronously.

A good idea would be to follow this tutorial here for using AJAX with Wordpress as the subject is too broad to give in one answer.

> #### [Getting Loopy – Ajax Powered Loops with jQuery and WordPress](http://wp.tutsplus.com/tutorials/getting-loopy-ajax-powered-loops-with-jquery-and-wordpress/)
>
> In this tutorial, we give you a starting point for creating AJAX interaction in your blog. The tutorial covers enqueueing scripts, setting up an AJAX handler, how to get a file outside of WordPress to use WordPress functions and access the database, and logic for loading posts on user page scroll.